# What modifiers are turned off by the Monk-given Challenges?

Tags: cross-code

What modifiers are turned off by the Monk-given Challenges?

Is it all modifiers, from Equipment and Circuits? Or is it just the ones from Equipment?

I don't have the Circuit Points to buy something obvious like Assault's:

> Melee attacks fire additional small projectiles for 20% of the base damage.

Which would be useful in Extra Frosty, if Additional Heat Projectiles can melt Ice Walls...